# TypeError: t.PVP.toFixed is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Acabo de montar my aplicacion que he desarrollado con `ReactJS` cundo lo pruebo en `Localhost` no hay  ningun problema, pero no funciona en el servidor, saliendome este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ninguna de las formas funciona, en todo los casos, sale el mismo error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque sale?, si uso el mismo navegador, funciona normal en `localhost` pero no `desplegado`

Answer (score 0):

Quizá en producción obtengas otro tipo de dato, puedes usar parseFloat, de manera que i recibes un string lo cambies a float

```
t.total = parseFloat(t.PVP).toFixed(2);
```